# Combine 2 rows into 1 row (Start and End times)

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by, window-functions, gaps-and-islands

I am not sure how to word this but I have `Start` and `End` times in separate rows, and I want to merge them into a single a row. In this sample data, it's basically tracking/logging project times:

```
Project  Type    Time
A        Start   1:00
A        End     1:10
B        Start   2:00
B        End     2:10
B        Start   2:30
B        End     2:45
C        End     3:00
D        Start   3:10
D        End     3:20
```

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
Project  Start    End
A        1:00     1:10
B        2:00     2:10
B        2:30     2:45
C        NULL     1:10
D        3:10     3:20
```

The 2 parts that are odd are that:

- I may have multiple start/end time pairs for the same project (such
  as Project B above), possibly back to back or separated on the same day
- I may have some missing start or end
  times.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?  I couldn't find anything on Stackoverflow that had these same requirements.

Comment: What do you want if you have START START END END ?

Comment: I would take the first START and Pair it with the first subsequent END.  The following END would have a NULL paired START time

Comment: ... and the second START would be paired with a NULL END time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is some kind of gaps-and-island problem.

I would approach this with `lag()` and a window `sum()`. A new group starts everytime consecutive records types are not `'Start'`  followed by an `'End'`.

```
select 
    project, 
    min(case when type = 'Start' then time end) Start,
    max(case when type = 'End' then time end) [End]
from (
    select
        t.*,
        sum(case when type = 'End' and lag_type = 'Start' then 0 else 1 end) 
            over(partition by project order by time) grp
    from (
        select
            t.*,
            lag(type) over(partition by project order by time) lag_type
        from mytable t
    ) t
) t
group by project, grp
order by project, grp
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=d50b04c1adaafc1477ade61d2412fff5)**:

```
Project | Start | End 
:------ | :---- | :---
A       | 1:00  | 1:10
B       | 2:00  | 2:10
B       | 2:30  | 2:45
C       | null  | 3:00
D       | 3:10  | 3:20
```

Comment: @Gordon Linoff does present a good question.  Chronologically, if there are multiple START times before the first END, the first START should be paired with the first END,  Any other START times in between should be paired with NULL END times.  I worked with DB Fiddle here but couldn't figure out how do it with Lag:  [link] https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=36120bbc616767ef6b22228509053969 [/link]  Is there a way to tweak this?

Answer (score 2):

We can try using pivoting logic here, with the help of `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Project, Type ORDER BY Time) rn
    FROM yourTable
)

SELECT
    Project,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'Start' THEN Time END) AS Start,
    MAX(CASE WHEN Type = 'End'   THEN Time END) AS [End]
FROM cte
GROUP BY
    Project,
    rn
ORDER BY
    Project,
    rn;
```

[image: screen capture of demo below]

### Demo

Comment: This works pretty well for a single dangling "END" but it didn't pair correctly if I add another correctly paired "START" and "END" after the dangling "END" time.  I tested it with the Project B section here:   [link]  https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=84eeb1f3d781ba46db59ce324cee84c7 [/link].  The B 2:30 START should be in the 3rd B row, rather than the 2nd B row.  Is there a way to tweak this SQL statement?

Comment: @Error500 I answer based on the data which I see, not based on data I don't see.  In this case, you should have asked a better question with data which explains all your edge cases.  My answer works for the data you did show.

Comment: Sorry, I was testing with other potential data that might get thrown my way.  I do appreciate the response, though

Comment: The @GMB answer is along the lines of what you would need if you could have many missing data points.  Indeed, in that case your question is a standard gaps and islands problem.